# NavigationLink Dismisses after Textfield Value is Updated to Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to make something similar to the iOS notes app but for journaling; basically, I want there to be a list of journal entry cells users can scroll through which each display a detail view after they're clicked on where the user can view and edit their journal entry. The updating works fine, the only issue is that `JournalDetailView` dismisses itself after `updateEntry()` is called (after the user taps the "Done" button). I'm guessing this is because `updateEntry()` forces the view to reload, but I'm not sure how to get around this.

Here's the model:

```
struct JournalEntry: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    @ServerTimestamp var date: Timestamp?
    var text: String
    var userId: String?
}
```

Here's the view code:

```
struct JournalCellView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: JournalViewModel
    @Binding var addButtonTapped: Bool
    @State var showDetail = false
    @State var entry: JournalEntry
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: JournalDetailView(vm: vm, entry: $entry, text: entry.text), isActive: $showDetail, label: {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                    Text(entry.date!.dateValue(), style: .date)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.system(size: 18))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(.bottom, 3)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack {
                    Text(entry.text)
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }.padding()
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18).foregroundColor(.white))
                .padding(.vertical, 4)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDetail = true
                }
                .onAppear {
                    if addButtonTapped {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                           showDetail = true
                        }
                        addButtonTapped = false
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}
```

```
struct JournalDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject var vm: JournalViewModel
    @Binding var entry: JournalEntry
    @State var text: String
    @State var isTyping = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: { Image(systemName: "chevron.left").foregroundColor(.burgundy) })
                
                Spacer()
                if isTyping {
                    Button(action: {
                        endEditing()
                        updateEntry()
                        isTyping = false
                    }) {
                        Text("Done")
                            .foregroundColor(.burgundy)
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("")
                }
                
            }.padding(.vertical)
            
            Text(entry.date!.dateValue(), style: .date)
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isTyping = true
                }
            Spacer()
        }.padding()
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
    func updateEntry() {
        vm.updateJournalEntry(docID: entry.id!, date: entry.date!, text: text)
    }
}
```

Here's `updateJournalEntry()`:

```
func updateJournalEntry(docID: String, date: Timestamp, text: String) {
        db.collection("journals").document(docID
        ).updateData(["date": date, "text": text, "userId": Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid])
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around this by only updating after the view would be dismissed naturally using `.onDisappear` and `.onReceive`. Not the cleanest solution, but it works. If someone has another suggestion, please contribute!

```
.onDisappear {
            updateEntry()
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
            updateEntry()
        }
```